# Getting array from a string using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Code:

```
<script language="javascript1.2">
   var re = /^\[\[.+$/;
   var str = '[[FirstName]] [[LastName]] watched "[[$Title]]" and sent you the following               
             comment and link:[[iaf_message/5]][[#if iaf_message/6 
              No]]http://webcasts.advanstar.com/acc/iaf/1/[[$PROGRAMID]]/Clicking the 
             URL above will take you to the webcast: "[[$Title]]" 
             [[#else]]http://webcasts.advanstar.com/acc/iaf/1/[[$PROGRAMID]]/?
              _IAFSegment=[[$SEGMENT]]&_IAFTime=[[$posmmss]]Clicking the URL above will 
              take you to the webcast "[[$Title]]" at the point in the program that 
              [[/User/FirstName]] thought would be most relevant to you.
              [[#endif]]Message from Advanstar Communications[Sender IP: [[$IP]]] If 
              you believe you have received this email in error, or for customer 
              service at Accela Communications, please send a message to 
              mailto:support.getinfoadvanstar.com';

  var myArray = str.match(re);
  console.log(myArray);
</script>
```

I want to fetch all values which are all present inside [[ ]] in an array using regular expression. Please help me.

Comment: please copy and paste the code as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var myArray = str.match(/\[\[.+?\]\]/g).map(
    function(x){ return x.replace(/\[|\]/g,"");
});
```

Comment: @Shanmugam glad to have helped.

Comment: @Shanmugam don't forget to mark it as answer by clicking on the tick mark

Comment: If you can't use .map, use a library like jquery or underscore which provides .map. However, most HTML5-enabled browsers support .map nowadays, althought many companies have windows XP installed and use internet explorer 8, so don't have default .map function.

Answer (score 1):

This should work in all versions of JavaScript:

```
var mystring = "[[foo]] .. [[bar]] ... [[baz]]";
var pattern = /\[\[([^\]]*)\]\]/g
var array = [];
match = pattern.exec(mystring);
while (match !== null) {
  array.push(match[1]);
  match = pattern.exec(mystring);
}
```